# Remove divs after 20 using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Divs of class=message are generated using a post which pulls data and puts it in the page. Now, I want to remove the lower divs after it reaches 20

```
<div class="message">test</div>
<div class="message">test</div>
<div class="message">test</div>
.
.
.
<div class="message">test</div>
```

So i need a sort of function to remove the remaining divs (from bottom) as i am adding to the top.

Also when a div appears, I want it to sort of fade in. How do i achieve that? i receive data in chunks so its something like

```
html = '<div class="messsage">1</div><div class="message">2</div>';
```

Now I tried this but its really not fading in. i would like it to glow yellow and get back to normal (bonus)

```
$("#data").prepend(html).fadeIn(2000);
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [gt](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/gt) selector, to match all elements with an index above the given one:

```
$('div.message:gt(20)').remove();
```

To your second question, you could use the [prependTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prependTo) function, which returns the newly added element, and you could hide the element, and then fade it in:

```
$(html).prependTo('#data').hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: Should be gt(19) though. Zero-based index :)

Comment: yep perfect. it answers my first question. any help with the second question?

Answer (score 0):

For animating color transitions, use the [color animations plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color).